# How to check if Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel has TPROXY

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy, kernel, transparent-proxy, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Digital Ocean's Ubuntu 14.04 image and needs the kernel to be compiled for `TPROXY`. Is there a way to check whether the current kernel supports `TPROXY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On SUse 11 Sp2

```
 node01:~ # grep TPROXY /boot/config-3.0.38-0.5-default 
 CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY=m
 CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=m
 node01:~ # uname -r
 3.0.38-0.5-default
```

I don't know the kernel version of ubuntu 14, but anyway, try grep in your kernel config under /boot Filesystem

Comment: Did the grep on the config and got `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=m` but not `CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY=m`. What does `m` means and does not having the other line means `TPROXY` is not supported?

Comment: m means it is compiled as a kernel module. TPROXY IS supported on the default Ubuntu 14.04 kernels.

Comment: So without `CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY=m` should work as well?