# Is HAProxy built with TPROXY on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-14.04, transparent-proxy

Ubuntu 14.04 has TPROXY ([How to check if Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel has TPROXY](https://serverfault.com/questions/622492/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-14-04-kernel-has-tproxy)).

How do I find out if the version of HAProxy packaged for 14.04 is compiled with TPROXY?

Answer (score 2):

Run `haproxy -vv` and look and look for `OPTIONS = USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1`

The packaged haproxy for ubuntu 14.04 is NOT built with TPROXY